# Преобразование даты между строковыми представлениями

Tags: python, python-3.x, локализация, datetime

Мне приходят данные в виде 'Март 1, 2010', 'Сен. 1, 2010' и т.п. Меняю им вид вот так:

```
def date_convertion(datetime):
    res = datetime.split(' ')
    res.reverse()
    return (res[0] + '-' + res[2][:-1] + '-' + res[1][:-1])
```

`datetime` получаю вот такой:

```
['Март 1, 2010']
```

на выходе функции это уже вот так:

```
['2010-Март-1']
```

Вопрос: как "Март" преобразовать в "03"? Создать словарь (он же ассоциативный массив) и искать по ключу значение или можно это сделать иначе?

Comment: Приведите кусок кода, который Вы попытались написать сами для решения Вашей задачи. Пока непонятно, что у Вас не получается

Comment: проблема с "запихиванием" данной строки в список, как работать дальше со списком я знаю, но засунуть строку в список я пытаюсь вот так dict([[x for x in datetime.split('.')],])

Comment: Измените ваш вопрос!

Comment: Формат строк фиксированный? Месяц всегда по-русски записан?

Comment: Неясно также, зачем вы используете dict и split? Эти подробности только запутывают. Либо поясните, либо уберите.
Кроме того, у вас тут два вопроса: преобразование строки, добавление её в список. Что именно вы хотите сделать? Обязательно уточните, чтобы вопрос не закрыли, как непонятный!

Comment: Теперь вопрос понятен! Я дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: `datetime` это название стандартного модуля и класса внутри него -- не нужно использовать это имя для других целей -- это вызывает путаницу.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Python strptime finnish](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33375709/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format

Answer (score 7):

При преобразовании из одного строкового формата в другой, особенно если входной формат нефиксированный и возможны вариации, то полезно использовать промежуточный объект-дату, чтобы убедиться что значения были интерпретированы корректно.

```
входная строка -> объект-дата -> выходная строка
```

Например:

```
datetime.strptime("входная строка", "формат") ->
datetime объект -> 
dt.strftime("формат вывода")
```

### setlocale() вариант

Если русская локаль установлена для программы или известно её название на данной платформе, то можно её активировать и попробовать распознать входные строки, используя фиксированный [список форматов](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import locale
from datetime import datetime

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8') # the ru locale is installed

date_strings = ['Март 1, 2010', 'Сен. 1, 2010', '2015-Апрель-26']
print(date_strings)
date_formats = '%B %d, %Y',    '%b %d, %Y',    '%Y-%B-%d'

dates = []
for date_str in date_strings:
    date_str = date_str.replace('Сен.', 'Сент.') # fix the abbr.
    for date_fmt in date_formats:
        try:
            dates.append(datetime.strptime(date_str, date_fmt).date())
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    else:
        print('failed to parse %r' % date_str)

output_date_strings = list(map(str, dates))
print(output_date_strings)
```

#### Вывод

```
['Март 1, 2010', 'Сен. 1, 2010', '2015-Апрель-26']
['2010-03-01', '2010-09-01', '2015-04-26']
```

### ICU вариант

Если есть возможность установить [PyICU](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU), то можно использовать несколько локалей независимо от наличия соответствующей системной локали и без изменения глобального состояния программы (может быть полезно в многопоточном приложении) [[синтакс ICU форматов для времени]](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime
import icu # PyICU

date_strings = ['Март 1, 2010', 'Сен. 1, 2010', '2015-Апрель-26']
print(date_strings)

df = icu.SimpleDateFormat('', icu.Locale('ru'))
output_df = icu.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')

output_date_strings = []
for date_str in date_strings:
    date_str = date_str.replace('Сен.', 'Сент.') # fix the abbr.
    for pattern in 'LLLL d, yyyy', 'yyyy-LLLL-dd':
        df.applyPattern(pattern)
        try:
            output_date_strings.append(output_df.format(df.parse(date_str)))
        except icu.ICUError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    else:
        print('failed to parse %r' % date_str)

print(output_date_strings)
```

Результат такой же как у первой программы.

### str.replace() вариант

Если входные данные более разнообразны, то можно ещё добавить предварительный шаг, который сделает их более регулярными, например, как `date_str.replace()` выше (можно словарь использовать со списком замен). Например, можно избавиться от зависимости на локаль, заменяя все названия соответствующими цифрами:

```
for old, new in [('Март', '3'), ('Сен.', '9'), ('Апрель', '4')]:
    date_str = date_str.replace(old, new)
```

После этого можно использовать `datetime.strptime()` c `'%m %d, %Y'`, `'%Y-%m-%d'` форматами без `setlocale()` вызова.

Comment: `PyICU` выглядит очень интересно...

Comment: @MaxU: ICU функциональна, но больше выходцам из C++/Java может быть знакома. Из интересных (c небольшой кривой обучения, более на Питон похожих), [можно на pendulum модуль](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) посмотреть (начало хорошее, не знаю как развиваться будет)

Comment: Спасибо! На Win64 этот модуль надо с бубном и плясками ставить... ;)

Comment: @MaxU: я вижу [бинарные wheels для osx и linux](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pendulum/) (подозрительно нет колёс для Винды, хотя [сборка на appveyor тестируется](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/sdispater/pendulum/build/job/8x4avdevb5cmcxfc)--по крайней мере чистый Питон без C ускорителей работает). Попробуйте issue открыть о binary wheel on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

## Кратко

Многое в решении вашей проблемы зависит от формата строки.

Если названия месяцев соответствуют русской локали и записаны либо полностью, либо сокращённо до трёх букв, то можете воспользоваться стандартной библиотекой `datetime`. В противном случае, если единого формата нет, можете задать словарь замен. Например (для двух месяцев):

```
month = {'Март': '03', 'Апр.': '04'}
```

Использовать его в вашем случае легко: `month[res[2][:-1]]`.

Небольшое замечание. Решение с использованием `reverse` и `split`, конечно, работоспособно, но не очень хорошо читается. Я бы использовал на вашем месте регулярные выражения. Тогда при замене формата строки изменения в программе будут минимальными.

## Замена с помощью datetime

Для начала задайте локаль (достаточно один раз в начале программы). Если у вас система уже настроена на русский язык, то достаточно выполнить следующие команды:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

Если язык системы другой, то вместо пустых кавычек укажите требуемую локаль.

При помощи метода `strptime` вы можете проанализировать строку на соответствие некоторому формату.

Пример:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime("Апр. 6, 2015", "%b. %d, %Y")
print(d)
```

> 2015-04-06 00:00:00

Здесь `%b` — краткое название месяца в текущей локали, `%d` — номер дня, `%Y` — номер года (4 цифры).

В переменной `d` будет находиться экземпляр класса `datetime`, который можно привести к любому другому виду.

В вашем случае:

```
print(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

> 2015-04-06

Перечисленный операции можно объединить в одну функцию и использовать её для добавления элементов в список:

```
def date_convert(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s, "%b. %d, %Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

[date_convert(d) for d in dates]
```

Здесь `dates` — список строк, хранящих даты в указанном вами формате.
Если требуется одновременно использовать две локали, то действия с датами можно выполнять, например, внутри `with` написав контекстный процессор.

[Библиотека `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

Comment: да, но это время я беру из другого ресурса и это совершенно не привязанные даты к дате и времени локальной машины.

Comment: В приведённой программе нет привязки к дате локальной машины. Тут просто анализируются строки по определённому формату. Главное, чтобы вы правильно указали локаль (то есть языковые настройки), а то он будет ждать названий месяцев на английском.
Формат, конечно, можете поменять под себя на другой.

Answer (score 2):

**Добавление элемента в список или в ассоциативный массив**

Добавление элемента в список производится с помощью функции `append`:

```
my_list.append( new_element )
```

Другой способ:

```
my_list += [ new_element ]
```

Добавление в ассоциативный массив выполняется так:

```
my_dict.update({ new_key : new_element })
```

или ещё проще:

```
my_dict[ new_key ] = new_element
```

Это если говорить в общем. У вас же вопрос немного туманный и не совсем понятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

**Преобразование даты между форматами**

Преобразование даты осуществляется обычно с помощью функции `strptime`, которая из вашей строки сделает объект даты, с которым можно выполнять дальнейшие манипуляции, в том числе форматирование в другой формат.

Это будет выглядеть так:

```
  d = datetime.datetime.strptime(d_string, fmt)
  d_string2 = d.strfime(fmt2)
```

В данном случае я преобразовал исходную строку `d_string` из формата `fmt` в формат `fmt2`, результат записан в `d_string2`.

(правда это к спискам не имеет никакого отношения).

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать следующее: у меня есть строка вида '2015-Апрель-26' я хочу сделать ее в виде  '2015-04-26' для этого я думаю использовать словарик со списком месяцев в виде moons({'Апрель': 04}) и мне нужно как-то организовать поиск по данному словарю

Comment: Если названия месяцев всегда либо полные (Апрель) или сокращённые до трёх букв (Апр), то самому создавать словарик не нужно, воспользуйтесь strptime, он знает про русские названия месяцев.

Comment: Не надо руками парсить дату, используйте strptime

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools, datetime, icu

_Replace = [('фев', 'февр'), ('ноя', 'нояб'), ('май', 'мая'), ('сен', 'сент'), ]
MonthReplace = (_Replace + [(s.capitalize(), r) for (s, r) in _Replace])  # для автозамены + capitalize
AllLocales = (En, Ru,) = list(map(icu.Locale, ['en', 'ru', ]))
TZ = icu.ICUtzinfo.getDefault()  # time zone, ~ в 2012г была другая, эти даты парсит на час назад
s_rus = 'авдимнопсфчя'  # первые буквы имен месяцев и недель
S_Rus = set(s_rus + s_rus.upper())
IcuDateMasks = ['dd/MMM/yy HH:mm:ss', 'dd/MMM/yy HH:mm', 'EEE, dd MMM y HH:mm:ss', 'EEE, dd MMM y HH:mm', 'EEE, dd MMM y', 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss y', ]  # http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
DateMaskForIcu = {(mask, lcl): icu.SimpleDateFormat(mask, lcl) for mask in IcuDateMasks for lcl in AllLocales}

@functools.lru_cache()
def str_to_datetime(datetime_str: str) -> 'datetime.datetime':
    (dtime_str, lcl) = _find_locale(datetime_str.split('+', 1)[0].strip())
    for mask in IcuDateMasks:  # выбрать правильный формат маски
        try: return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(icu.DateFormat.parse(DateMaskForIcu[mask, lcl], dtime_str), TZ, ).replace(tzinfo=None)
        except icu.ICUError: continue
    raise UserWarning(f'"{dtime_str}" не распознана в локали "{lcl}", ни по одной из масок "{IcuDateMasks}" !!!')

def _find_locale(datetime_str: str) -> (str, 'icu.Locale'):
    if any((s in datetime_str) for s in S_Rus):  # рус locale
        for (s, r) in MonthReplace:
            if s in datetime_str:
                datetime_str = datetime_str.replace(s, r, 1)  # 'правильные' имена месяцев
                break
        return datetime_str, Ru
    else: return datetime_str, En

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(str_to_datetime('04/июн/12 11:56'))  # 2012-06-04 11:56:00
    print(str_to_datetime('15/Jan/19 2:49'))  # 2019-01-15 02:49:00
    print(str_to_datetime('15/Фев/19 20:42:01'))  # 2019-02-15 20:42:01
    print(str_to_datetime('Пт, 02 ноя 2018 14:26:00'))  # 2018-11-02 14:26:00
```