# Почему нужно переопределять локаль для вывода локализованнах строк (например strftime())?

Tags: python, локализация, datetime, локаль

В соответствии [с документацией](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), strftime() должен возвращать локализованные значения даты и времени (название месяцев и дней недели и т.д.), однако делает это лишь после явной установки локали:

```
>>> locale.getlocale() # Проверим текущую локаль
('ru_RU', 'UTF-8')
>>> d1.strftime('%A')
'Sunday'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')
'ru_RU.UTF-8'
>>> locale.getlocale()
('ru_RU', 'UTF-8')
>>> d1.strftime('%A')
'Воскресенье'
```

Почему на русском начинает выводить только после переопределения локали, хотя до этого она и так была `('ru_RU', 'UTF-8')`? Более того, достаточно просто сделать resetlocale:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('ru_RU', 'UTF-8')
>>> locale.getlocale()
('ru_RU', 'UTF-8')
>>> d1.strftime('%A')
'Sunday'
>>> locale.resetlocale()
>>> d1.strftime('%A')
'Воскресенье'
```

Answer (score 7):

Все программы на *nix системах (не только `python`) стартуют, используя C (POSIX) locale до тех пор пока они не вызовут `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')`, чтобы активировать пользовательскую locale.

Если не хотите locale активировать для процесса, то можно использовать библиотеки, которые явно позволяют язык выбрать, такие как PyICU ([пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419422/23044))—есть полегче библиотеки, которые могут работать для конкретной задачи, например [`humanize`](https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import humanize  # $ pip install humanize
>>> _ = humanize.i18n.activate('ru_RU')
>>> humanize.naturaltime(datetime.datetime.now())
'сейчас'
```

> **В:** но почему же `locale.getlocale()` выдаёт `ru_RU`?

Я бы также ожидал, что-нибудь вроде `(None, None)` вместо `('ru_RU', 'UTF-8')` до того как `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')` вызвано в программе. Из [документации: *"Returns the current setting for the given locale category"*](https://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.getlocale)  не очевидно, что пользовательские настройки из переменных окружения ([`LC_*`, `LANG`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07)) читаются, а не текущая локаль по умолчанию ([*"The POSIX locale is the default global locale at entry to `main()`"*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html)) возвращается до вызова `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')`.

`locale` модуль это тонкая обёртка вокруг соответствующей C функциональности, в частности, поведение может зависеть от платформы. [Текущая реализация `locale.getlocale()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5ec2f7b6d95aee485ee7cbaa67a70e58084e969e/Lib/locale.py#L565-L581) эквивалентна C [`setlocale(category, NULL)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html), которая запрашивает текущую настройку для локали ([*"query the current global locale setting"*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html)).

Почему *"the current global locale setting"* не равна *"the default global locale"* до вызова `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')` я не понимаю. Может дело в слове `setting` vs. `locale`, то есть текущая *настройка* до вызова `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')` берётся из переменных окружения (`LC_*`, etc), а текущая *локаль* до вызова `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')`, используемая `strftime()`, является C (как и положено). Но это чистая спекуляция с моей стороны.

Comment: ок, но почему же locale.getlocale() выдаёт ru_RU?

Comment: @jumpjet67: попробовал на комментарий ответить, но кратко: не знаю.