# Преобразование даты Python

Tags: python, строки, дата, datetime

Я получаю с JSON объекта дату в формате:

`2017-01-29 09:00:00`

как мне преобразовать ее в:

`01/29 вс 09:00`?

Подскажите пожалуйста, как преобразовать полученную дату?

Comment: `2017-01-29 09:00:00` - это строка или `datetime` объект?

Comment: 2017-01-29 09:00:00 - это строка

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Преобразование даты между строковыми представлениями](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/419321/23044)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно так:

```
In [12]: s = '2017-01-29 09:00:00'

In [13]: import datetime

In [14]: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%m/%d %a %H:%M')
Out[14]: '01/29 Sun 09:00'
```

PS у меня системные настройки английские, поэтому - `Sun`

**UPDATE:**  благодарю [@jfs за совет по использованию PyICU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618888/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-python/618892?noredirect=1#comment858166_618892), который позволяет динамически поменять локаль в программе, не трогая системных настроек:

```
import datetime
import icu

s = '2017-01-29 09:00:00'

df = icu.SimpleDateFormat('MM/dd eee HH:mm', icu.Locale('ru'))

d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(df.format(d))
```

Результат:

```
01/29 вс 09:00
```

Comment: [Можно PyICU использовать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419422/23044), чтобы глобальную локаль не трогать.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за PyICU! добавил пример в ответ...