# Как создать проверку сегодняшнего дня? Как вывести погоду только на сегодня?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Прошу вашей помощи, имеется код:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime, date, time

city = input()
r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?&units=metric&q=%s&appid=295f286d77a869327ed8dfae72a0542d' % (city))
data = r.json()
temp = data["list"]
for id in temp:
    tmp = id["main"]["temp"]
    tmp = str(round(tmp))
    dt = id["dt_txt"]
    print(dt + " - " + tmp + "°C")
```

Который по названию города выдает погоду на 5 дней. Вот только выдает он периодами по 3 часа. Т.е. за 24 выдаст 8 значений. За 5 дней - 40

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что бы задать выводимое количество значений, в коде я могу прописать `temp = data["list"][*number*]`. Проблема в том, что погода выводится в зависимости от времени, т.е. если я запущу скрипт в 18, то он покажет погоду начиная с 18:00. Если я запущу в 9 утра, то покажет с 9 утра.
Исходя из этого, я не могу задать в `temp = data["list"]` `[8]` так как выведится погода не только на сегодня, но и на завтра. А постоянно исходя из времени вписывать нужное количество выводимых значений у меня нет.

Как я могу сделать проверку, что если до конца сегодняшнего дня остается 6 часов, значит в `temp = data["list"]` предать значение `[2]`. Если остается 12 часов - то передать `[4]`.

Буду вам очень благодарен за ответ

Comment: Вы можете пару вариантов попробовать: (а) задать параметры http-запроса, чтобы только для интересного вам интервала времени значения бы возвращались (если поддерживает сервис-погоды—почитайте его доки) (б) фильтруйте на клиенте: `data = [id for id in temp if start_time <= id['dt'] < end_time]`

Answer (score 1):

Чем не нравится такой вариант. Мы легко можем получить текущую дату, затем поглядеть кол-во часов. И -- уаля:

```
import datetime
time = datetime.datetime.now()
number = (24 - time.hour - 1) // 3
print data["list"][number]
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable` ругается на `number = ((24 - time[2] - 1) // 3) `

Comment: Поправил. В Вашем посте * number * -- это int?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
from datetime import datetime

def dt_convert(dt_str, fmt_from='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', fmt_to='%m/%d %a %H:%M'):
    return datetime.strptime(dt_str, fmt_from).strftime(fmt_to)

today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

forecast_today = \
['{} - {}°C'.format(dt_convert(x['dt_txt']), round(x['main']['temp']))
 for x in data['list']
 if x['dt_txt'].startswith(today)
]
```

Результат:

```
['01/25 Wed 00:00 - -14°C',
 '01/25 Wed 03:00 - -14°C',
 '01/25 Wed 06:00 - -13°C',
 '01/25 Wed 09:00 - -11°C',
 '01/25 Wed 12:00 - -8°C',
 '01/25 Wed 15:00 - -9°C',
 '01/25 Wed 18:00 - -16°C',
 '01/25 Wed 21:00 - -15°C']
```

PS если надо выводить дату в "неродной" (отличной от системной) локали, то можно воспользоваться [PyICU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618892/211923) или [Pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/) (могут возникнуть трудности с установкой на Win64)