# Форматирование даты прописью на русском языке

Tags: python, дата, text, format

Как в Пайтоне перевести дату из строки в формате `dd.mm.yyyy` в прописную форму на русском языке, оставив год числом?

`"01.07.2009"` → `"первое июля 2009 года"`

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Преобразование даты между строковыми представлениями](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/419321/23044)

Answer (score 7):

Надеюсь я не ошибся, что формы одни и те же там всегда:

```
def get_date(date):
    day_list = ['первое', 'второе', 'третье', 'четвёртое',
        'пятое', 'шестое', 'седьмое', 'восьмое',
        'девятое', 'десятое', 'одиннадцатое', 'двенадцатое',
        'тринадцатое', 'четырнадцатое', 'пятнадцатое', 'шестнадцатое',
        'семнадцатое', 'восемнадцатое', 'девятнадцатое', 'двадцатое',
        'двадцать первое', 'двадцать второе', 'двадцать третье',
        'двадацать четвёртое', 'двадцать пятое', 'двадцать шестое',
        'двадцать седьмое', 'двадцать восьмое', 'двадцать девятое',
        'тридцатое', 'тридцать первое']
    month_list = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня',
           'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря']
    date_list = date.split('.')
    return (day_list[int(date_list[0]) - 1] + ' ' +
        month_list[int(date_list[1]) - 1] + ' ' +
        date_list[2] + ' года')
date = input()
print(get_date(date))
```

https://repl.it/F7n7/0

Comment: Спасибо, я именно такой подход и имел в виду, чтобы через инпут и списки, но самостоятельно пока не смог оформить. Все работает отлично

Comment: В общем случае, стоит разделить распознавание ввода и форматирование результата. `get_date()` можно обозвать `date2words(d)`, где `d` это `datetime.date`, а не строка. В этом случае, если входной формат другой, то достаточно будет изменить код, считывающий дату, не трогая код, который её форматирует.

Answer (score 2):

Мне не попадалась библиотека, которая умеет день месяца как порядковое числительное словами в среднем роде на русском выводить (datetime, pendulum, `icu.DateFormat`, babel, humanize, num2words, inflect не умеют). Конечно, легко руками преобразовать для выбранных языков:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pendulum # $ pip install pendulum

d = pendulum.from_format('01.07.2009', '%d.%m.%Y')
ordinal_day_word = ['', 'первое', 'второе', 'третье', ...][d.day]
print(ordinal_day_word + d.format(' %B %Y года', locale='ru'))
# -> первое июля 2009 года
```

Если другие языки поддерживать не надо, то достаточно здесь только `d = datetime.strptime('01.07.2009', '%d.%m.%Y')` из стандартной библиотеки использовать и месяцы (`d.month`) также руками в слова в нужном падеже и регистре букв преобразовывать, например, как в [ответе @Кирилл Малышев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/623782/23044).

Код создаёт промежуточный объект-даты, чтобы убедиться в её корректности, [чтобы не принимать ошибочные даты типа: `30.02.2000`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419422/23044).

Answer (score 1):

На корректную работу с датами на русском языке можно настроить и стандартными средствами **Linux** и **Python**.

На современном **RedHat**-семействе (8.x) это выглядит примерно так: установка необходимого пакета локализации на русский язык и настройка локали и раскладки клавиатуры в системе:

```bsh
yum install glibc-langpack-ru
localectl set-locale LANG=ru
localectl set-keymap ru
reboot
```

После этого **Linux** начнет лучше понимать и отображать русские тексты.

Теперь **Python**. Сам по себе он не подхватит системную локаль, нужны дополнительные вызовы функций модуля `locale`:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'ru_RU.utf8'
```

После этого **Python** начнет работать с русскими данными как с родными:

```
>>> import datetime

# Получаем тип datetime из даты, заданной строкой по-русски
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('11 марта 2020', '%d %B %Y')
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 0, 0)

# Наоборот,
# получаем строку с русским отображением даты из переменной типа datetime
>>> today = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(today, '%d %B')
'29 марта'
>>>
```

Вариантов же, стандартными средствами получать строку с датой, где число представлено словом (`первое`,`второе`,`третье`, и т.д.) - нет.