# дата в питоне в текст

Tags: python, дата

как преобразовать дату в текст. Например '2013-11-02' в 'второе ноября 2013 года'.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы старались решить эту проблему сами, столкнулись с проблемами, перерыли весь интернет в поисках ответа, ничего не нашли, и будучи готовым предоставить демонстрацию своего решения с нерешенной ошибкой, обратились на stackoverflow?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Форматирование даты прописью на русском языке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623775/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5)