# regex для дат разного формата

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Файлы содержат даты форматов 4 вида:

```
31.12.2017 23:59:59
31-12-2017 23:59:59
2017.12.31 23:59:59
2017-12-31 23:59:59
```

Как с помощью regex отфильтровать нужные?

Я попробовал использовать

```
[\d-\.]+ [\d:]+
```

Так как по аналогии у меня был regex для формата 2017-12-31 24:59:59

```
[\d-]+ [\d:]+
```

Но python выдает ошибку:

```
raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

Как нужно исправить regex?

Comment: заэкранируйте "-"

Comment: связанный вопрос [Преобразование даты между строковыми представлениями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/419321/23044)

Comment: jfs, ты прав, это я допустил ошибку

Comment: Вместо явного сложного регулярного выражения, [можно использовать datetime.strptime](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/419321/23044), чтобы проверить даты или [простой regex + datetime конструктор](https://ideone.com/N4fPJ1) как по ссылкам показано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данное регулярное выражение делит дату на 4 группы : первые три - дата, четвёртое - время (заметьте, оно не распаршено, т.е. это `str = "24:59:59"`) :

```
(\d+)[\.|\-](\d+)[\.|\-](\d+)\s(.*)   #Первый вариант
(\d{2,4})[\.|\-](\d{2})[\.|\-](\d{2,4})\s(.*)   #Второй вариант
```

Если вы хотите отлавливать именно даты такого формата 2017-12-31 24:59:59, то:

```
(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})\s(.*)
```

И на всякий случай оставлюка [это](http://www.exlab.net/files/tools/sheets/regexp/regexp.pdf) здесь.

Comment: спасибо, очень помогает. Но почему вы оставили время как (.*). Разве нельзя его тоже преобразовать в regex

Comment: Имеете в виду, чтобы и его парсило, можно, но это я предлагаю сделать вам, в интернете множество онлайн сервисов для составления регулярных выражений. А как сделать? Смотрите на дату и делайте по аналогии, будут вопросы - спрашивайте, но ведь главное, чтобы вы с этим научились работать.  Вот замечательный сервис https://regex101.com/