# strptime для месяца в родительном падеже

Tags: python, datetime, локализация

Как можно преобразовать строку вида `1 января 2018` в `datetime`-объект? (месяц записан в родительном падеже)

Формат `%B` ожидает получить название месяца в именительном падеже, поэтому код

```
datetime.strptime('1 января 2018', '%d %B %Y')
```

выдаёт

> ValueError: time data '1 января 2018' does not match format '%d %B %Y'

Конечно, можно написать таблицу имён месяцев и работать с ней, но может есть решение получше.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Преобразование даты между строковыми представлениями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/419321/23044) (LLLL формат работает)

Answer (score 5):

Как [уже сказал @jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767102/strptime-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b5#comment1193869_767102) можно использовать модуль [PyICU](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU/):

```
import icu
from datetime import datetime

def parse_date(s_date, fmt='dd MMMM yyyy'):
    f = icu.SimpleDateFormat(fmt, icu.Locale('ru'))
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(int(f.parse(s_date)))

dates = ['1 января 2018','31 декабря 2017','1 марта 2002','8 июля 1997']    

[parse_date(s).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for s in dates]
```

Результат:

```
In [69]: [parse_date(s).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for s in dates]
Out[69]: ['2018-01-01', '2017-12-31', '2002-03-01', '1997-07-07']
```

PS чтобы установить PyICU под Windows может понадобиться [Python wheel file](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyicu)

Answer (score 4):

Преобразование падежей я бы сделал с использованием замечательной библиотеки pymorphy2.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding:utf-8

# для преобразования слов
import pymorphy2
# для понимания русскоязычного названия месяца
import locale

from datetime import datetime

# устанавливаем русскоязычный формат даты и времени
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')

# инициализируем парсер для разбора слов
m = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

# pymorphy2 работает со строками только в юникоде
datestr = u'1 января 2018'

day, month, year = datestr.split(' ')

# преобразуем название месяца в именительный падеж с заглавной буквы
new_month = m.parse(month)[0].inflect({'nomn'}).word.title()

dt_obj = datetime.strptime(' '.join([day, new_month, year]).encode('utf-8'), '%d %B %Y')
```

Comment: по сравнению с простой заменой по словарю, сложно это выглядит.

Answer (score -1):

проще будьте, а...

```
def month_from_ru_to_eng(month):
    out = ''
    if month == 'января': out = 'jan'
    if month == 'декабря': out = 'dec'
    if month == 'февраля': out = 'feb'
    if month == 'марта': out = 'mar'
    if month == 'апреля': out = 'apr'
    if month == 'мая': out = 'may'
    if month == 'июня': out = 'jun'
    if month == 'июля': out = 'jul'
    if month == 'августа': out = 'aug'
    if month == 'сентябся': out = 'sep'
    if month == 'октября': out = 'oct'
    if month == 'ноября': out = 'nov'
    if month == 'декабря': out = 'dec'
    return out
```

Comment: Вы тоже не усложняйте, сделайте чтобы код был выполняемым.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне кажется что данный код было бы лучше оформить с использованием словаря, ну и как я написал в конце своего вопроса я рассматривал такой вариант, но мне кажется что он далёк от идеала. В любом случае спасибо.