# Конвертировать строку в дату

Tags: python, datetime

Имеется строка

```py
new_date = '1 Сентябрь 2015'
```

Пытаюсь конвертировать в дату:

```py
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "ru_RU")
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_date, '%d %B %Y')
print(date_time_obj.date())
```

Но выходит ошибка:

```py
ValueError: time data '1 Сентябрь 2015' does not match format '%d %B %Y'
```

Ошибка возникает из-за падежа, в котором написан месяц (с написанием 'сентября' работает). Как это можно изменить, если месяц может попасться любой? (то есть просто `replace('сентябрь', 'сентября')`) не подойдет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767102/strptime-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5 + связанные вопросы

Comment: У меня распарсилось (windows 10, python 3.10). А вот "Сентября" уже нет: "ValueError: time data '1 Сентября 2015' does not match format '%d %B %Y'"

Comment: не понимаю, почему у некоторых работает с именительным падежом только, а у других только с родительным..

Comment: Насчет replace. Можно сделать словарь месяцев https://pastebin.com/uYG3WKuj, а лучше к номеру месяца https://pastebin.com/sRpasGHe . При желании это можно доработать регулярками: в ключе шаблон регулярки, типа '`сентябр.`' (https://pastebin.com/2kFxsVqX), тогда будет только один вариант